# How do I use a phototransistor for a line follow robot?

Tags: arduino, phototransistor

I'm building a line follow robot for a competition in 2 months and I'm using Arduino but I have no idea how to find the line (what sensors needed). I did some research and discovered that if I can use a photo transistor and red LED to detect the line. I wanted to know would this set-up work? Will the data received be fast and accurate?

Comment: Light's pretty fast, so... yeah.

Comment: Why would someone want to close this as "too broad"? I just skip questions I don't understand.

Answer (score 4):

This  is a very very ... common application - if you search the web you will find a very large number of methods and circuits and practical guides.

[This page - Line following robot sensor](http://www.electroschematics.com/5976/line-following-robot-sensor/) is one of the many you could find.
The advantage of this method over many others is that it uses an integrated :"transmitter receiver" IC (a CNY70) which means you do not have to worry about relative alignment of the two parts - you just positiuon the sensor near the line and detect the reflected (or not) signal. The CNY70 is an old IC but also very available.
If using it read the data sheet carefully - you'll find that the transmitter and receiver polarity are opposite - ask me how I know :-) (from long long ago).

[image]

https://www.google.co.nz/search?q=line+following+robot&espv=2&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=tvzeU-qfL87j8AX4-4KQCg&ved=0CB0QsAQ&biw=2133&bih=1194&dpr=0.9

The rest of the circuit is more complex than necessary - butr not too much so - you can take input to the Arduino from "SIG".

---

Lots of detail here.
Fig 1 shows what you want.
LM324 IC is cheap and available.
He uses 4 sensors - how many you use is up to you.
He also provides AVR code.

[Award winner from VingPeaw Competition 2543](http://chaokhun.kmitl.ac.th/~kswichit/LFrobot/LFrobot.htm) , the robot built with 2051, L293D, and four IR sensors. Simple circuit and platform, quick tracking and easy-understand program using C language.

---

[Simple 2 sensor LFR](http://www.elektronobi.com/eng/robot/line_follow_robot.html) looks good

[And another](http://letsmakerobots.com/robot/project/brainless-line-following-robot)

[and more ...](http://www.tombot.net/beam/linefollowingrobotcircuit2.html)

---

---

[**Here are many many many examples**](https://www.google.co.nz/search?q=line+following+robot&espv=2&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=tvzeU-qfL87j8AX4-4KQCg&ved=0CB0QsAQ&biw=2133&bih=1194&dpr=0.9) - each is linked to a related page

Comment: by transmitter and receiver is this what you kinda mean http://www.ebay.com.au/itm/5x-Infrared-Emitter-and-IR-Detector-Phototransistor-Pair-Ships-FAST-from-USA-/131131031358?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item1e8804bf3e&_uhb=1

Comment: @user3901882 - Could be. Looks like it.Sounds like it. May even be. It's on ebay. It has no part number . It has no spec sheet. It's not shrouded to keep out exterior light. The plastic on the detector MAY block background light well. Or not. It may even work well for you if you can determine it's characteristics. Or not. **OR** for just slightly more, all up, you could buy genuine CNY70, known characteristics, available data sheet. From eg [Digikey](http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en?x=0&y=0&lang=en&site=us&keywords=cny70) or ...

Comment: ... from [Mouser](http://nz.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Vishay/CNY70/?qs=%2fha2pyFaduj8YpDhNNtXszq4w32cl%2fAjUjdOwQUvJUM%3d)
 or [a dozen or so other sellers](http://www.findchips.com/search/cny70) but, where's the fun in that compared to buying something random off ebay ? :-)

Comment: PS - yes, it is quite likely that the device off ebay would work well for you. BUT given your time frame and level of experience, buying something that you know is genuine and that you know as much about as possible AND that has off the web notes re operation and more, sounds like a good idea. To me, anyway.

Comment: I've bought from ebay and from distributors and for such a small project I'd go for ebay for sure. Your opinion about experience is right though, moreover with a genuine sensor you can get tons of schematics like the one you posted. Anyway is such a complex circuit really needed? I'd have thought a pull up (polarizing) resistor on the photoq would be enough.